# How to get records between 7am and 3pm in ist from utc time zone in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to get data between 7am and 3pm but I'm getting records between 12pm to 5pm because i did not converted to IST hours for hours chek in last clause "`a.timestamp.Hour > 7 && a.timestamp.Hour < 13)`". How do I  convert utc time to IST hours so that I can get desire data.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
var items = Pirs
    .Where(a => 
        !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA=") && 
        (fromDate == null || 
        fromDate.Value.Date <= 
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), 
                TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date) && 
        (toDate == null || 
        toDate.Value.Date >= 
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), 
                TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date) && 
        a.timestamp.Hour > 7 && a.timestamp.Hour < 13)
    .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12))
    .Select(g => g.First()).OrderBy(a => a.timestamp);
```

sample data

```
timestamp   "2017-07-21T18:26:01.004Z"
```

Comment: Do `a.timestamp` and `fromDate` represent times in "India Standard Time" or "Utc Time"?

Comment: It appears that you are taking a string, converting it to an IST time zone date, and then trying to convert it *from* Utc time (which it's not).

Comment: day wise its getting correct result but only "a.timestamp.Hour > 7 && a.timestamp.Hour < 13" is wrong . after adding this where clause records not getting as per time in indian st time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the records between specific time in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371552/how-to-get-the-records-between-specific-time-in-entity-framework)